# jQuery Two Tab Containers Using Same Code, How do I Excecute Event Only Inside Clicked Container?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabs

I want to be able to use two identical (only difference are the tab ID's) tab containers with the same piece of jQuery.

I almost got it working, but my problem is that as soon as I click on a tab from one of the Tab boxes (Tab Box One & Tab Box Two), the content of the other container hides.

I think I need to use $this somewhere, or perhaps create a few variables, since I'm repeating my code (DRY, I know I know..)

Any advice on how to not make the two Tab Boxes affect each other? I've tried for hours, but I can't wrap my head around it..

**Codepen:**

http://codepen.io/StrengthandFreedom/pen/xwKENJ?editors=101

**Code:**

```
// Hide content info from all divs
$(".tabContent").hide();

// Show tabContent from the first child of each Tab Box
$(".tabContent:first-child").show();

// Add active class to first list item tab of each Tab Box 
$("ul.tabs li:first-child").addClass("active").show();

$("ul.tabs li").click(function() {

  // Remove active class on last child
    $("ul.tabs li:last-child").removeClass("active")
    $(this).prev().removeClass("active");
    $(this).next().removeClass("active");

  // Add class active to the one clicked
     $(this).removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");

 // This need to hide only the content of the clicked div
    $(".tabContent").hide();

    var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    $(activeTab).fadeIn(1500);
    return false;
  });
```

Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Reduced code.
You can reduce it more..

```
$(".tabContent").hide();
$(".tabContent:first-child").show();
$("ul.tabs li:first-child").addClass("active").show();
var tabs= $("ul.tabs li");
tabs.click(function() {

    tabs.removeClass("active")
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(".tabContent").hide();
    var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    $(activeTab).fadeIn(1500);
    return false;
  });
```

**Update:**
as per @nevermind comment
It can be reduce further

```
tabs.click(function() {
    tabs.removeClass("active")
    $(this).addClass("active");
    // $(".tabContent").hide(); 
    var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    $(activeTab).fadeIn(1500);
    $(activeTab).siblings().hide();
    return false;
  });
```

Comment: Reduced, but doesn't work how OP wants - all tabs are affected.

Comment: Yes thats why i said that it can be reduced more :)

Comment: Actually, same number of lines as in your code, just: $(".tabContent").hide(); -> which affects all tabs (undesired behavior) is removed, and:  $(activeTab).siblings().hide(); - added. Otherwise - nice code. :)

Comment: yes .. I should have changed the same...  we can reduce it more.. we can also use css eg for all tab content we can use display:none rather that using $(".tabContent").hide();

Comment: Thank you so much (to both of you). I already tried using "siblings" but I used it the wrong place, your code makes a lot of sense!

Comment: One question, Vishu238, you say that we can use "Display: none" in CSS rather than 'hide' in jQuery, but is there any advantage (performance) of doing that? Isn't it just moving 'hide' from jQuery to CSS? I'm curious as I want to learn from this. Cheers :-)

Comment: Its is alway said to do DOM manupulation as less as you can.. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
You can use event.target 
event.target
<div id='1'/>
<div id='2'/>

in js function you can do like this
if(event.target.id =='1'){
// code goes here
}
else if(event.target.id='2'){
//code goes here
}
```